# Creating a Cookie Crawler Tool for Extracting Cookie Information using Node.js or Ruby

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby, web, web-crawler

I am looking to develop a simple crawler tool that can extract cookie information from a webpage using either Node.js or Ruby. Although I would like to share some code, I'm unsure about the best libraries to use for creating the crawler. The main objective of this crawler is to retrieve all the cookies present on a page, based on a URL parameter, which may include asynchronous loading through Google Tag Manager.

For instance:

`SITE_URL = "youtube.com"`

The expected output should be:

`> _ga

> _gid
> ...`

I am open to implementing the crawler in either Node.js or Ruby, but I have a slight preference for Node.js.

Could anyone provide guidance on the best libraries or approaches to create this cookie crawler?

Answer (score 0):

To create a simple crawler tool that extracts cookie information from a webpage using Node.js, you can leverage the Puppeteer library. The setTimeout function acts as a blocking mechanism, allowing enough time for all cookies, including third-party ones like '_ga', to be loaded.

Below is an example implementation using Puppeteer:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const DELAY = 20000; // setTimeout
const URL_SITE = 'https://www.youtube.com/'; // site to be accessed

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(URL_SITE);

    setTimeout(async () => {
        // Get cookies using page.cookies()
        const cookies = await page.cookies();

        // Alternatively, you can extract cookies using page.evaluate()
        const cookiesPorEvaluate = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return document.cookie.split(';');
        });

        console.log(cookies); // Output all cookies
        console.log(cookiesPorEvaluate); // Output cookies extracted using page.evaluate()

        await browser.close();
    }, DELAY);
})();
```

Please ensure you have Puppeteer installed in your Node.js environment using npm install puppeteer before running the code.

This script will launch a headless browser, navigate to the provided URL_SITE, and wait for the DELAY time before extracting and displaying the cookies using both page.cookies() and page.evaluate().

Remember to customize the URL_SITE variable to point to the specific website you want to crawl for cookies.